# bsdtar fails to unpack firefox xpi

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, unzip, xpi, bsdtar

Extensions to Mozilla applications like Firefox or Thunderbird are distributed in [XPI format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPInstall), which is basically a ZIP archive. As such, the `unzip` utility can extract it. `bsdtar` is able to do so, as well.

But if the archive contains a `META-INF` directory, where signature files are usually stored, the file contents are not unpacked correctly. Only when unpacked with `unzip`, the extension correctly shows up as signed in Firefox.

If you want to recreate my test case, download and unpack with both tools any signed extension, for example [*Hide Tab Bar With One Tab*](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/429664/addon-429664-latest.xpi). If you click this link in Firefox, it will propose to install the extension, so you may want to use `curl` or `wget` instead.

```bash
$ curl -LO 'https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/429664/addon-429664-latest.xpi'
$ mkdir bsdtar unzip
$ bsdtar -C bsdtar -xf addon-429664-latest.xpi
$ unzip -d unzip addon-429664-latest.xpi
$ diff -r bsdtar unzip
Files bsdtar/META-INF/manifest.mf and unzip/META-INF/manifest.mf differ
Files bsdtar/META-INF/mozilla.rsa and unzip/META-INF/mozilla.rsa differ
Files bsdtar/META-INF/mozilla.sf and unzip/META-INF/mozilla.sf differ
```

What does `bsdtar` do differently than `unzip`? Is this a bug?

Comment: I am unsure whether this question may perhaps be better suited for [the Unix StackExchange site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), so feel free to migrate it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39856780/10558 talks about the requirements of the XPI file, maybe bsdtar trips up on that type