# Add-on "appears to be corrupt" when trying to install my add-on's .xpi file in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xpi

I am trying to install an extension in Firefox 45 (same happens with Firefox 49), but Firefox does not allow me to do that, indicating that

```
This add-on could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt.
```

The way I am trying to install it is simply by **dragging the .xpi file** our team developed, into the Firefox window. This extension is based on [MozRepl](https://github.com/bard/mozrepl/), but with some improvements.

Previously, I tried to install it but I couldn't as it was not signed (extensions in Firefox versions from 43 onwards require signing). I followed every step in order to sign it, according to this post: [Signing a XPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Signing_a_XPI). I am almost certain I could sign it correctly, but now the error Firefox displays is different: "This add-on could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt."

[image]

It seems that I am not creating the .xpi file correctly, but I am not sure which is the correct structure it should have. I tried different folder structures, but with no success.

Also, I checked the Browser Console to see what error is logged in, but I didn't found it really helpful. Here it is:

[image]

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7KHv4DP9WZiUjB2REZ3Wk1Hcm8/view?usp=sharing) is a link to the .xpi file in case you want to check its content. Note that I tried moving the files manifest.mf, zigbert.rsa and zigbert.sf outside the META-INF folder, but it didn't work either.

Has anyone stumbled across an error like this when trying to install an add-on? Any ideas of what maybe happening?

Comment: if you rename the file with a .zip extension, can you open it as a zip file and read the contents of the file inside? if not, then it is indeed corrupt

Comment: Please provide the directory structure you have in your *.xpi* file. Alternately, make your *.xpi* file available for us to look at it.

Comment: @JaromandaX, yes I can unzip the file and see its content.

Comment: @Makyen: I edited the post to include a url to the .xpi file

Comment: @nicolasd92, I downloaded your *.xpi* file. Based on a superficial look, the basic file/directory structure appears to be correct (*chrome.manifest* and *install.rdf* in the root directory, *META-INF* (the signatures) present (I did not test them, but they superficially appear correct), etc.). However, due to the complexity of your add-on (e.g. **it contains *.dll* and *.exe* files**), I am unwilling to actually attempt to install it for security reasons (I would have to burn a VM, which I don't feel like doing at the moment).

Comment: @nicolasd92, I should have been a bit more thorough.  You appear to be using LZMA compression. Use "Deflate" as your compression method.

Comment: @nicolasd92, In addition, as mentioned in my answer, you have signed this extension yourself.  It needs to be signed by Mozilla, not you. See [Signing and distributing your add-on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution). While this is not causing your current error, it will be an error as soon as you have a correctly compressed *.xpi* file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### The *.xpi* file must use *only* "deflate" compression or uncompressed

The zip implementation within Firefox only supports [uncompressed files or files compressed with the "Deflate" algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIZipReader#extract()). You will need to create the *.zip* archive using the compression method "Deflate" instead of the "LZMA" which you are currently using. How to do so will depend on the tools you use to create your archive.

Personally, I use a batch file/shell script to create the *.xpi* file as I describe in detail in my answer to "[Firefox extension .xpi file structure: description, contents, creation, and installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31043045/3773011)". The basics are that I use the `zip` command line tool which defaults to "deflate" or uncompressed. I use the `-1` option to provide the fastest compression. Firefox/Mozilla use *.xpi* files both to package the files, but to also increase file access speed. The important quality is not a high compression ratio, but that the files can be accessed quickly. Unless Firefox is not an WebExtension and explicitly told to unpack the add-on by the *install.rdf* option [`<em:unpack>true</em:unpack>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#unpack) (WebExtensions don't have *install.rdf* files), the add-on will be installed as the *.xpi* file and all access to the add-on will be as the *.xpi* file.

Note: Given that your extension contains *.dll* files, you may need to have your add-on installed unpacked by using [`<em:unpack>true</em:unpack>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#unpack).

### Wrong signing method used. It must be signed by Mozilla, not yourself.

While it is not the error you are currently seeing, as soon as you fix the problem with your *.xpi* format, you will encounter an issue with your extension being signed by the wrong signature. You signed your extension with your own signature. It was not signed by Mozilla. This will not work. It must be signed by Mozilla, not yourself.You mentioned that you followed the directions in the MDN page [Signing an XPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Signing_a_XPI?document_saved=true). However, as is clearly stated at the top of that page, the directions on that page are outdated and no longer work. You should have followed the link in the note to the page **[Signing and distributing your add-on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution)**. The note at the top of the page states:

> Note: These instructions are outdated. For an extension to work in Firefox it must be **signed by Mozilla, not by yourself**. See **[Signing and distributing your add-on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution)**. [Emphasis added]

There are also a variety of questions here on Stack Overflow which address the signing issue.

Answer (score 12):

Like stated in other answer it happens for unverified/unsigned extension.

But sometimes for testing you might want to use unverified/unsigned extension.
As a hack/workaround to install unverified/unsigned extensions following worked for me on Firefox version 45:

1. Launch Firefox and hit - about:config
2. Search for 'xpinstall.signatures.required'
3. Either double click on the row OR set the value to false and close

Now retry installing the extension and it should work.

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore, unfortunately, even though the setting still exists.

Comment: Sorry, yes, it does work, but only on Firefox nightly.

Comment: @phil294 the original question is about Firefox

Comment: I know, and Firefox nightly is a Firefox version, but not the release one. In other words, your answer does not work with the "normal" FF versions that everyone uses.

Comment: @phil294 Not sure about the current version but when i posted the answer I was using Firefox release version and it was working with that

Answer (score 9):

I think there is something not clearly documented, I'd like to share my experience.

1. Developed my extension and `zip`ped all the files
2. Selected `On your own` for `How to Distribute this Version` step and uploaded `.zip` to [AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/)
3. Then, on the next page, I see a signed `.xpi` file available for download. I downloaded it and tried to install via "about:addons -> Install Add-on from file"

   1. I get `corrupt add-on` error in this case
4. After receiving e-mail from `amo-editors@mozilla.org`, I went to my add-on's page and clicked on `.xpi` file link there and **it worked!**

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue when I compressed the folder containing my addon rather then just the files within.

**Don't Compress the Parent Folder of your Manifest**

[image: Screenshot]

For example, on Windows CTRL+Click on your *manifest and any other files or subfolders;* right click and select `Send to > Compressed Folder` and you should be good to go.

*Note: from the browser console screenshot we can tell this isn't the issue in this case, but even so this is a common problem to the `This add-on could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt` error.*

Comment: Doing this using 7zip with the store compression level did it for me

Comment: Doing this on `about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox`, *not* `about:addons` worked for me.

Comment: Doing this with Mac default compression worked for me when attempting to make a Mozilla Thunderbird extension.

Answer (score 5):

The message `because it appears to be currupt` can point to various problems. You can see a more detailed error message in the Browser Console at ctrl+shift+J.

As soon as you edit *anything* inside an xpi file and try to add it manually to the browser, an extension ID needs to be provided inside the manifest.json if it isn't already, with `applications.gecko.id` or `browser_specific_settings.gecko.id`. For example, altering any single character in https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quick-js-switcher/ shows `Invalid XPI: Error: Cannot find id for addon` in Browser Console, so you add

```json
"applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "some@example.com",
      "strict_min_version": "1.2.3"
    }
  }
```

to the manifest.json as well and it works: But **only** with `about:config`'s `xpinstall.signatures.required` set to `false` *on Firefox versions that actually respect this setting*, [which *excludes* the normal release one](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1298806) because apparently Mozilla hates its userbase. You need FF Nightly or the like, I'm using [LibreWolf](https://librewolf.net/).

[source](https://gitlab.com/librewolf-community/browser/linux/-/issues/293)

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to a tangential question when the "The add-on downloaded from this site could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt" error message starts appearing when trying to install any Thunderbird add-on.  There are some other sites where this tangential question has been asked but the pages got archived:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/7942yu/the_addon_downloaded_from_this_site_could_not_be/  (for FF)
- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1319105
- http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=2739869

Since this question here still allows replies, just wanted to add that this can occasionally start happening for all add-ons if the user's local Thunderbird profile files gets corrupt in some specific way.

In such case, I recommend restarting Thunderbird in "safe mode" with all add-ons disabled via "Help" -> "Restart with Add-ons Disabled...", and then restarting back to the "regular" mode via "Help" -> "Restart with Add-ons Enabled".  After that installation of add-ons may work again.

Even though this is not the answer to this specific question, hope this tip is helpful for whoever hits this specific tangential but similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on firefox 52, just downgrade the addon to a lower version designed for firefox 52 or less will fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

## Temp Load Extension via Debug Add-Ons

You can use the Add-Ons page, and click the Gear icon, and choose the **Debug Add-Ons** menu option.

Then, you can load your extension's `.zip` file without needing to sign it.

It's temporary, probably only for the current session, but it's good for debugging.

[image]