# How can I install WebExtensions for personal use most easily?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I created a few WebExtensions for Firefox that are for personal use. However, now that I want to start using them I find that there is a fairly cumbersome [signing process](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution). Because these plugins are for my own use only, and will not leave my computer, I prefer to install them without having to go through the signing process. What is the easiest way to do this?

I have tried to install an unsigned package (just like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081558/how-to-package-an-unsigned-firefox-webextension)). However, even though I set `xpinstall.signatures.required` to `false` in my `about:config`, Firefox still doesn't let me install this plugin. However, I now read that I must have Developer Edition, Nightly, or ESR version for this to work. So, with a regular Firefox edition (version 50), what is the easiest way to get this done?

If I go to about:debugging then I can install my plugins just fine and they work great, so I was thinking perhaps there is a way to automate this and always activate them through about:debugging upon starting Firefox?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable signature checking for Firefox add-ons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31952727/how-can-i-disable-signature-checking-for-firefox-add-ons)

Answer (score 1):

You can sign your extension but keep it unlisted, you describe this as "cumbersome" but without any elaboration...

You can also disable signing in the unbranded Firefox builds:
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Add-ons/Extension_Signing#Unbranded_Builds

Comment: Thanks but I have a regular, "branded" Firefox, and am looking for a solution that does not involve changing browsers. I am looking to avoid the extra time and hassle it takes to sign the extensions. Which in my case does not add value and I therefore consider cumbersome. Thanks.

Comment: You've defined what you're looking for so narrowly that you're asking for something that doesn't exist.