# Error when trying to install my webextension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, xpi

I've signed myself my extension and now it's an XPI. Whenever I try to install the extension from my website, it works perfectly on my computer (running on Linux). When I try to install it on Firefox on Windows, it doesn't: it says something like

> The file seems to be corrupted

This is the command I'm running under Linux to *zip* it before signing it:

```
cd ~/MyExtension
zip extension.xpi * -r
```

Why? Is there a way to solve?

Comment: can you share source code ?

Comment: @FastSnail unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be a code problem. It seems to be a signing/zipping problem. Read the OP post update.

Comment: did you try to install it on windows before signin ?

Comment: @FastSnail yes, it works when installing it manually (in `about:debugging`) and so without signing it.

Comment: There is no way for us to be certain of what your problem is without access to your *.xpi* file.

Comment: Probable duplicate: [Add-on "appears to be corrupt" when trying to install my add-on's .xpi file in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39854127)

Comment: Related, with more information: [Firefox extension .xpi file structure: description, contents, creation, and installation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30865644)