# Firefox: switch tabs with Alt + [0-9]

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

On Arch Linux I was able to switch tabs by pressing Alt+[tab_num].

I have to work on Windows, where firefox uses Ctrl+[tab_num].

It's really annoying. Ctrl is not very well positioned for this kind of switching + I am used to Alt+[tab_num] instead of Ctrl+[tab_num].

Is there an easy way how to manage/change this in Firefox ? Any extention that does exactly this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the script in https://gist.github.com/zbraniecki/000268ea27154bbccaad190dd479d226. I write a working code(at least in my Firefox) below

manifest.json

```
{
  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "selecttab@braniecki.net",
      "strict_min_version": "48.0"
    }
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "SelectTab Gnome Shortcut Override",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "An extension that overrides the default select-tab modifier key.",

  "permissions": ["tabs"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "commands": {
    "selectTab1": {
      "suggested_key": { "default": "Alt+1" },
      "description": "Activate Tab 1"
    },
    "selectTab2": {
      "suggested_key": { "default": "Alt+2" },
      "description": "Activate Tab 2"
    },
    "selectTab3": {
      "suggested_key": { "default": "Alt+3" },
      "description": "Activate Tab 3"
    },
    "selectTab4": {
      "suggested_key": { "default": "Alt+4" },
      "description": "Activate Tab 4"
    },
    "selectTab5": {
      "suggested_key": { "default": "Alt+5" },
      "description": "Activate Tab 5"
    },
    "selectTab6": {
      "suggested_key": { "default": "Alt+6" },
      "description": "Activate Tab 6"
    },
    "selectTab7": {
      "suggested_key": { "default": "Alt+7" },
      "description": "Activate Tab 7"
    },
    "selectTab8": {
      "suggested_key": { "default": "Alt+8" },
      "description": "Activate Tab 8"
    },
    "selectTab9": {
      "suggested_key": { "default": "Alt+9" },
      "description": "Activate Tab 9"
    }
  }
}
```

backgroud.js

```
browser.commands.onCommand.addListener(async (command) => {
  let num = parseInt(command.substr(9, 10)) - 1;
  let tabs = await browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true});
  if (tabs.length < num) {
    return;
  }

  if (num === 8) {
    browser.tabs.update(tabs[tabs.length-1].id, {active: true});
  } else {
    browser.tabs.update(tabs[num].id, {active: true});
  }
});
```

Then you may refer to [How to publish a FireFox WebExtension for local installation only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45148795/how-to-publish-a-firefox-webextension-for-local-installation-only) to install it permanently.

Comment: this does not achieve desired behaviour, I need: switch tabs with Alt + [0-9]

Comment: @Talos Sorry for misunderstanding your requirements, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 6):

I was annoyed at this too, and made [an addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/alt-number-to-switch-tabs/) to deal with it which you should be able to install from the official website.

Comment: This add-on does the job, thanks!

Comment: Excellent thanks, it's useful also because VS Code uses Alt + num on Windows, so switching tabs and applications in Web-dev land was: in Code Alt + n for tabs, Alt + Tab to get to the browser, CTRL + n to tab switch!  Now it is Alt alt-the-way. Much easier on the mind and body.